# Getting NumberFormat of Range using Excel interop in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read excel file in c#.
I want to read range of cells as it is way faster than reading cell one by one:

```
Range rbeg = (Range)sheet.Cells[1, i + 1];
Range rend = (Range)sheet.Cells[totalRowCount, i + 1];
Range range = sheet.get_Range(rbeg, rend);
column = (object[,])range.Value2;
```

The problem is when I want to get number format of cells by calling:

```
range.NumberFormat
```

I get System.DBNull. It works when I call it for single cell.

I want to distinguish between cells with numerical values and "%" values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb213677.aspx):

> [NumberFormat] returns Null if all cells in the specified range
>   don't have the same number format.

What were you expecting it to do in this case?

Comment: I was expecting it to act as Value - return array of formats. One value in array for each cell in range. Thanks for quick answer.